# Java store Swing table in Arraylist

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, arraylist

I have a class Person with attributes name and lastname. Person Objects I store in PersondDatabase in an Arraylist. Also I have a swing table with columnnames "name" and "lastname" with editable cells.

If a name and lastname are filled in, I want to make a new entry in Database.
For example when fill Joe (name) and Jones (lastname) in swing Table in my Database is a new entry with Joe Joe, but it should be Joe Jones.

```
class Person {
String name; String lastname; 
 ...
}

 public class PersonDatabase{

   ArrayList<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>();

   public  newEntry(String name, String lastname) { // adds a Person to     
                                                   //Database
    persons.add(new Person(name,  lastname));   
 }
}


class TabelModel extends AbstractTableModel {
   PersonDatabase db = new PersonDatabase()
    private String[] columnNames = { "name", "lastname" }; 
    private Vector<Object[]> rows = new Vector<Object[]>();  

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        String[] row = (String[]) rows.get(rowIndex);
        return row[columnIndex];
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex) { 
        rows.get(rowIndex)[columnIndex] = aValue;               
        int tmp = columnIndex++;
        db.newEntry((String)aValue,(String) getValueAt(rowIndex,tmp); 
        // Here i want to add a Person to Database          
        fireTableCellUpdated(rowIndex, columnIndex);
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have a `Person` object, you should using those in your `rows` data model. *"Database is a new entry with Joe Joe, but it should be Joe Jones"* - So I assume you've got code which inserts the row into the database? Which is likely where the problem is.  When `setValueAt` is called you need to determine two things.  Does the `Person` have a first and last name filled out. This should require you to check the values for the specified row

Comment: You should create your new entry in an `addRow(...)` method, perhaps an entry with default values if you want to create an empty row, or with data entered if you want to create a row showing the names. The setValueAt should change the state of the object whose row is being acted on.

Comment: @ MadProgrammer Yes, i have a method addRowToEnd

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Yes, i have a method addRowToEnd

So you need to invoke that method somewhere in your application logic to add an empty Person object to your "PersonDatabase".

```
public void setValueAt(...)
```

This method is invoked to update a single cell only. You should NOT be trying to invoke the `newEntry(...)` method of your database.

Instead you need to access the current Person object for that row and then update either the first or last name depending on which column your are updating.

So, an easier solution is to store the ArrayList of Person objects in the PersonTableModel. Note don't call your class `TableModel` that is an interface name and is confusing. Use a more descriptive name.

Check out [Row Table Model](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/21/row-table-model/) for a step-by-step example on creating a custom TableModel.

Comment: Thanks a lot very useful link.